# Django. Choosing a specific field - relation one-to-many

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I have two table and want to releated these with one-to-many.
One unity - many stat.

I try to select field but it not working.

Always my ForeignKey is **Unit.name**.
I want to use **Unit.id** as **ForeignKey** !!

I thought that the **Unit.id** can't be so for tests I tried another field **Unit.name2**, it also doesn't work.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field

```
class Unit(models.Model) :

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField( max_length=20, unique=True)
    name2 = models.CharField( max_length=20, unique=True)
    rase = models.CharField( max_length=10 )

class Stat(models.Model) :

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    unit_id = models.ForeignKey( Unit, to_field='name2', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='unit_id',)
    attack_type = models.CharField( 'attack_type', max_length=10 )
    attack_speed = models.DecimalField( 'attack_speed', max_digits=5, decimal_places=4 )
    attack_number = models.IntegerField( 'attack_number' )
```

Additional question.
If I left **Unit.name** as ForeignKey what happen when i change a **Unit.name** in the future? If name value will change in all related tables?

That's why I want to use **Unit.id** as a ForeignKey because **Unit.id** will not change but the **Unit.name** can.

Comment: Simply remove the `to_field`, since `id` is the primary key, it should do that automatically. But I don't know if you will be able to migrate this automatically...

Comment: I delete database and migration file and make new. 

It's not working i think. 
https://gyazo.com/4dc3d2073641714f437efd6f28ebd8ab

https://gyazo.com/04c211d54d0bd843cdc69c3e287cc862

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added **unique=True** also to AutoField in Unit model.

Also I change **Unit.id** to **Unit.unit_id**.

It seems it working.

```
class Unit(models.Model) :

    unit_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True, verbose_name='unit_id', )
    name = models.CharField( max_length=20, unique=True)
    name2 = models.CharField( max_length=20, unique=True)
    rase = models.CharField( max_length=10 )

    def __str__( self ) :
        string = 'unit_id: {} - {}'.format(self.unit_id, self.name)
        return string

class Stat(models.Model) :
    stat_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    unit_id = models.ForeignKey( Unit, to_field='unit_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='unit_id', )
    attack_type = models.CharField( 'attack_type', max_length=10 )
    attack_speed = models.DecimalField( 'attack_speed', max_digits=5, decimal_places=4 )
    attack_number = models.IntegerField( 'attack_number' )

    def __str__( self ) :
        string = '{0} {1} stat'.format(self.unit_id, self.attack_type)
        return string
```